# Adding condition to a column in an Athena view (SQL Presto)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a view with a column that I'd like to alter/add to. The column already exists but I want to add a CASE WHEN condition.

So I already did something like:

```
CREATE VIEW testing_view AS
SELECT code, tag
FROM database.testtable;
```

And I want to do something like:

```
ALTER(?) VIEW testing_view AS
SELECT code, tag
CASE WHEN "code" = "restricted" OR "code" = "rest" OR "code" = "rstd" 
THEN 'restricted' END "tag"
```

The goal is to update the tag column with these conditions.

I want to alter the view but if I have to create a new view with this condition I can do that too but I was having problems. Instead of adding to the existing column it made a new (second) column named tag with just the 'restricted' word in it. I understand why, given the code, but I can't figure out how to get what I want.

EDIT: I already have a case when condition for this table so trying to put in two ends up with an error that says:

> Column name 'tag' specified more than once

So my code is something more like:

```
CREATE VIEW testing_view AS
SELECT code, tag
CASE WHEN "code" = "example" AND "code" = '' THEN 'example' END "tag"
FROM database.testtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW testing_view AS
    SELECT code,
           (CASE WHEN code IN ('restricted', 'rest', 'rstd')
                 THEN 'restricted' ELSE tag
            END) as tag
    FROM database.testtable;
```

If your version of Presto supports `ALTER VIEW`, then you can of course use that.

The code in your question is not correct, so this fixes the syntax issues as well.